# Cual es la referencia de ensamblado para "RestClient, RestRequest y HttpBasicAuthenticator "

Tags: c#, visual-studio, embebido, restsharp

Estoy desarrollando para *Windows embedded 6.0* y pues quiero enviar correos, investigando encontré a **Mailgun** este me arroja el código el cual debe ir en proyecto el cual es éste:

```
 public static RestResponse SendSimpleMessage()
    {
        RestClient client = new RestClient();
        client.BaseUrl = "https://api.mailgun.net/v3";
        client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("api","key-2d624aae9621461bbaac333f01207b7a");
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
        request.AddParameter("domain","sandboxABCEDFGGHJKLOASDFDGDFGUI3456U5.mailgun.org", ParameterType.UrlSegment);
        request.Resource = "{domain}/messages";
        request.AddParameter("from", "Mailgun Sandbox <postmaster@sandboxABCEDFGGHJKLOASDFDGDFGUI3456U5.mailgun.org>");
        request.AddParameter("to", "Cristian <xxxxxx@xxxx.com>");
        request.AddParameter("subject", "Hello Cristian");
        request.AddParameter("text", "Congratulations Cristian, you just sent an email with Mailgun!  You are truly awesome!  You can see a record of this email in your logs: https://mailgun.com/cp/log .  You can send up to 300 emails/day from this sandbox server.  Next, you should add your own domain so you can send 10,000 emails/month for free.");
        request.Method = Method.POST;
        return client.Execute(request);
    }
```

El problema es que por ningún lado hace referencia cuales son las librerias o dll que se deben utilizar y pues por ese motivo me arroja errores en los siguientes lados, y los fragmentos `ParameterType` y `Method` no existe en el contexto actual y con el `RestClient`, `HttpBasicAuthenticator` y `RestRequest` este si me arroja el error

> No se puede encontrar el tipo o nombre de espacio de nombre "  " (falta una directiva de using o una referencia de ensamblado)

He estado investigando y pues sin suerte alguna, y pues también me gustaría saber sus sugerencias sobre como enviar correos por *Windows embedded 6.0*

Comment: Si aun es de utilidad para agregar las referencias busca desde el administrador de paquetes de Visual Studio en mi caso es la versión de 2017 que tiene como nombre **RestSharpSigned** o descargalo de la pagina : https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharpSigned/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que la dependencia que usas es [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/)

La instalación vía nuget seria

```
PM > Install-Package RestSharp
```

Aunque no estoy seguro si tenga ensamblado para la plataforma a la que quieres apuntar, pero lo mas fácil es intentar instalarlo y ver.

---

Si se va usar Visual Studio 2008 nos podemos ahorrar los "workarounds" y bajar directamente los dll de su pagina en [github](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/downloads)

Comment: en visual studio 2008 como se podría ser la instalacion por vía nuget

Comment: Pues quiza se mas facil bajar los dll, te adjunto el link en la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Intenta cambiando la línea que dice

```
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("api", "key-2d624aae9621461bbaac333f01207b7a");
```

por

```
client.Authenticator = new RestSharp.Authenticators.HttpBasicAuthenticator("api", "key-2d624aae9621461bbaac333f01207b7a");
```

Comment: Gracias por contribuir pero la pregunta ya tiene una respuesta aceptada ¿ Que realiza el cambio que sugieres ?, revisa [ask], saludos.